# Resize problem using jquery e.pageX and e.pageY

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I have a div which pops up when you hover over an image, the div floats 20px above the mouse where ever the mouse is over the image (it's a description for the image.) When I resize the window the position gets thrown way off. My thought for this is because it's still trying to get the old window e.pageX and e.pageY. Is there a way so that on resize of the window it recalculates the e.pageX and e.pageY?

Here is the snippet of code that calculates the div that is shown on image hover.

`mapPieceText.css({left: (e.pageX - (offset.left - 20)), top: (e.pageY - (offset.top + 20))});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are storing 'offset' as a fixed value.  You'll need to recalculate offset on page resize (or use a 'dom-live' jQuery method ).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but shouldn't it be `$(this).offset().top` ?